# FOS User Bundle Not Redirecting to fos_user_registeration_check_email after form submit

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle

I set `registration: confirmation: enabled: true` in **config.yml** and so everything works well as far as the email being sent and the user following the link but the problem is, after submitting the registration form, it redirects to the login page. Looking at _profiler I don't see any requests for `/register/check-email` either. I'm using FOS Userbundle v2.1.2 and symfony 3.4.14.

I'm using a third party php script and I feel like there's an option in the services.yml or config.yml that I can set to tell it to redirect to render the `check_email.html.twig` but i'm not sure what it is. I've actually deleted the entire checkEmailAction method that I suspected was the method handling the request and it's had no effect, the email still gets sent and same behavior.

**checkEmailAction** (method)

```
  /**
     * Tell the user to check their email provider.
     */
    public function checkEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->getSession()->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

        if (empty($email)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_register'));
        }

        $request->getSession()->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (null === $user) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_login'));
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/check_email.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }
```

**register_content.html.twig**

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

It's using Swiftmailer to send the email and so I'm thinking maybe there needs to be a listener attached to swiftmailer but I'm not sure.

**Route**

```
<route id="fos_user_registration_check_email" path="/check-email" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.registration.controller:checkEmailAction</default>
</route>
```

Also, for /register, the role is `IS_AUTHENTICATED ANONYMOUSLY` in my security.yml

**access control (security.yml)**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/account, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Are you sure the user is being created and is found here?

$user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);
if (null === $user) {
    return new RedirectResponse(
        $this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_login')
    );
}

Can you to log in as the registered user?

Comment: The user is created when the email is sent (in mysql) but if they try to log in before confirming the email, it says their account is disabled and doesn't log them in.

Comment: I tried commenting out the lines you referenced and set `$user` to a filler value like "dan1" and still redirects to login. I feel like this method isn't even doing anything because if I delete it, nothing changes but surely it should be doing something.

Answer (score 0):

In your config do you have have /register/check-email set up for anonymous access?

Something like

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/register/check-email, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: I added my access control settings, `^/register` looks like it's set up for anonymous access. Maybe I'm missing a special character?